# Loop through the key and value of an array object in HTML

Tags: html, arrays, angular, object

I have an array Object like this: `[key1:Array[3], key2:Array[1], key3:Array[3]]`. 
I want to display the keys and values in HTML like this:

```
key1 
item1 item2 item3
key2
item4
key3
item5 item6 item7
```

When I open the object, I just see

```
Array[0]
  >key1:Array[3]
  >key2:Array[1]
  >key3:Array[3]
```

I am using javascript with Angular2 and this is my attempt to access the array (which I found it in another stackover flow post)

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysArray">
   <span *ngFor="let v of generateArray(k)"> {{v}} </span>
</li>
generateArray(obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
}
```

But I am still not able to display either keys or values on HTML.

Comment: `[key1:Array[3], key2:Array[1], key3:Array[3]]` is **not** an "Array object" whatever you mean by that. It's a mutant object which could not exist. Do you want an array or an object? Do you mean `{key1:Array[3], key2:Array[1], key3:Array[3]}`? `ngFor` loops over the **indexes** of an **array** (with numerical indices). You cannot loop over the properties of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this?

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysArray">
   <span *ngFor="let v of k"> {{v}} </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used **`Object.keys`** in your template ?

if not than use it like this and get what you want , like this

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysGetter(keysArray)">
   {{k + ' : ' + keysArray[k]}}
</li>

keysGetter = Object.keys;
keysArray = {keyOne: [1,2,3,4], keyTwo: [1,2,4], keyThree: [1,3,4]};
```

**<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKeVKgH3Hi8MYbcdin80?p=preview)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this keys pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    "name": "keys",
})
export class Keys implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() {}

    public transform(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return value;
        }

        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            if (value) {
                keys.push({
                    "key": key,
                    "value": value[key],
                })
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

in your for loop you can now do this:

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysArray | keys">
   <span> {{k.key}} - {{k.value}} </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

since "k" is an object : {key1:Array[3]} with "key1" as key, you need to access it value:

1. Object.keys(k)[0] => this is the key
2. k[Object.keys(k)[0]] => this isthe value == Array

Result:

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysArray">
    <span *ngFor="let v of k[Object.keys(k)[0]]"> {{v}} </span>
</li>
```

Beside that solution, i will consider use this structure:

[{"key":key1,"value":Array[3]},{"key":key2,"value":Array[3]}, {"key":key3,"value":Array[3]}]

and then use it as :

```
<li *ngFor="let k of keysArray">
   <span *ngFor="let v of k.value </span>
</li>
```